# Boost precompiled headers problem

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, precompiled

I try to precompile Boost headers.

First experiment - with std:: headers. I create file std.hpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
// And other std:: headers
```

After that:

```
g++ std.hpp
```

Copy std.hpp.gch in /usr/include/c++/4.4.5

And write test program:

```
#include <std.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, precompiled world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Works fine.

Now try precompile Boost headers.

I create boost.hpp file:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
```

After that:

```
g++ boost.hpp
```

Copy boost.hpp.gch in /usr/local/include/boost

And write test program:

```
#include <boost/boost.hpp>

int main() {
    // Some code...
    return 0;
}
```

But got error:

```
main.cpp:2:33: error: /usr/local/include/boost/boost.hpp: No such file or directory.
```

Try, for experiment:

```
#include </usr/local/include/boost/boost.hpp>

int main() {
    // Some code...
    return 0;
}
```

Same error.

Try copy boost.hpp.gch in another place - same error.

If I put file boost.hpp in same place - works fine (so there is no problems with path):

```
ls /usr/local/include/boost | grep boost
boost.hpp
boost.hpp.gch
```

So compiler use boost.hpp header. But why compiler don't see precompiled boost.hpp.gch??

Comment: Maybe `/usr/local/include` is not in your include path. Try `g++ -I/usr/local/include`.

Comment: /usr/local/include is in my include path. In this path placed 'boost' dir. :-) And as I say, file boost.hpp in same path works fine, but boost.hpp.gch - not.

Comment: For experiment try `g++ -I/usr/local/include` - same error...

Comment: I try precompile separate boost-header: `g++ /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp`, after that remove qi.hpp from this place - same error.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a gcc bug as documented in http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46110